# SolrCloud admin page showing Slave (Searching)

Tags: solr, master-slave

I am not using the master slave settings in solrconfig(as far as I know) but still solr admin page shows this in browser.

```
                  Version        Gen             Size
```

Master (Searching)  1444735428179    4390         5.4 GB

Master (Replicable) 1444735488272    4391          -

Slave (Searching)   1444735428184    4390         5.4 GB

I am not able to understand why it is showing slave part. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever come up with any information on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [solr cloud shows slave(searching)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487892/solr-cloud-shows-slavesearching)